# Pass a variable with INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE statements

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-13

I am looking for the ways where could be possible to send some data with psql query statement. For example:

```
insert into mytable (id,name,site_id) values (default,'test',1);
```

Real structure of mytable:

```
id
name
```

With help of `site_id` variable I want to pass it's value in order to use it in triggers. In trigger:

```
if new.site_id=1 then 
...
else
...
```

If there is other methods of doing above could you please advise.

Comment: Welcome to the DBA.SE community. Depending on your version PostgreSQL there could be other means and ways of achieving what you are thinking of doing. Could you tag your version of postgresql? e.g. [`postgresql-9.6`](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/postgresql-9.6). Hit the [edit] link to add additional tags. Thanks.

Comment: There are *many* ways. The best - or even appropriate - way depends on undisclosed information. What's happening in that `IF` statement? Why not just save `site_id` to the table? Postgres version? Are you at liberty to change the relational design and/or add objects? Are there *actual* triggers? Roughly how many? Is `site_id` immutable for the same trigger? Show minimum sample code for an existing trigger (even if it does not work, yet).

Comment: Thank you all, I added PSQL version. I am doing some sort of replication app between several databases. For a while I've added a site_id to the table. Because without site_id the replication can go to inifinite loop between databases (triggers on CRUD). So this site_id only present now in this table only for that reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to use a custom [**updateable view**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createview.html#SQL-CREATEVIEW-UPDATABLE-VIEWS):

```
CREATE TABLE ins_tbl(
  id   int GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY
, name text
);

CREATE VIEW v_ins_tbl AS
SELECT *, NULL::int AS site_id
FROM ins_tbl;

-- trigger func
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION trg_ins_tbl()
  RETURNS trigger
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$func$
BEGIN
   CASE NEW.site_id
   WHEN 1 THEN  -- cascade insert
      INSERT INTO ins_tbl (name) VALUES (NEW.name);
      RETURN NEW;
   WHEN 2 THEN  -- propagate insert, but stop there
      INSERT INTO ins_tbl (name) VALUES (NEW.name);
      RETURN NULL;      
   WHEN 0 THEN  -- cancel silently
      RETURN NULL;
   ELSE  -- raise error
      RAISE EXCEPTION 'Unexpected site_id: %', NEW.site_id;
   END CASE;
END
$func$;

-- trigger
CREATE TRIGGER trg_insbef_ins_tbl
INSTEAD OF INSERT ON v_ins_tbl
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE FUNCTION trg_ins_tbl();
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=5d96df27ef7c7d0f2f1feec3905cfe05)*

Your desired `INSERT` works now, targeting the `VIEW`:

```
insert into v_ins_tbl (id, name, site_id) values (default, 'test', 1);
```

There is a [related example in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-trigger.html#PLPGSQL-VIEW-TRIGGER-AUDIT-EXAMPLE).

Not going into more details while your question is vague.
There are many subtle details to this solution. If you are unfamiliar, read up on views, triggers, default values, permissions, PL/pgSQL in general.

Comment: Thank you very much. I've changed the DB structure in oder it will work as I need. I am doing some sort of replication software between several databases. Your answer very useful, I need a time to to learn it D:.